# Ошибка при преобразовании строкового массива в массив типа double

Tags: java

Код:

```
        String[] split = s.split("\\t");
        time = split[0];
        for (String masss : split) {
            System.out.println(masss);
        }
        double[] track_mass = new double[split.length];
        for (int i = 0; i<split.length; i++) {
            try {
            track_mass[i] = Double.valueOf(split[i]);
            }catch(NumberFormatException e) {   }
        }

        for (double mass : track_mass) {
            System.out.println(mass);
        }
```

Строка s выглядит так: 
"0  0,21875 -0,02625    0,3625  -1,091  -4,7875 6,875   13,5    -0,0225 -0,05125    -0,0135625"

В массиве double получаются одни нули, почему ? Подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: Подсказываю: из-за запятой.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как уже заметил @Igor проблема в том, что в строке разделителем целой и дробной части выступает запятая, а для вашей локали разделителем является точка. Есть несколько способов решить эту проблему. Первый и, пожалуй, самый правильный - это использовать [java.text.DecimalFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) и явно указать символ разделителя:

```
DecimalFormat fmt = new DecimalFormat();
DecimalFormatSymbols symbols = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
symbols.setDecimalSeparator(',');
fmt.setDecimalFormatSymbols(symbols);

String[] tokens = s.split("\\t");
double[] track_mass = new double[tokens.length];
for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
    track_mass[i] = fmt.parse(tokens[i]);
}
```

Второй - это использовать [java.text.NumberFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html) с другой локалью:

```
NumberFormat fmt = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.FRANCE);

String[] tokens = s.split("\\t");
double[] track_mass = new double[tokens.length];
for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
    track_mass[i] = fmt.parse(tokens[i]).doubleValue();
}
```

И последний - тупая замена символов в строке:

```
double[] track_mass = Pattern.compile("\\t")
                             .splitAsStream(s)
                             .map(s -> s.replaceAll(",", "."))
                             .mapToDouble(Double::parseDouble)
                             .toArray();
```

Comment: Эм.. Разве parseDouble не будет из текущей локали разделитель брать?

Comment: Будет. Для русской локали разделитель - точка, соответственно `Double.parseDouble()` завалится на строке с запятой.

Comment: Для русской как раз запятая. Точка для английской.

Comment: Хмм... Вы правы, но я сейчас проверил у себя и, несмотря на то, что `Locale.getDefault()` возвращает ru_RU, Java требует разделителем именно точку.

Comment: Всем спасибо за комментарии!